# Why may Bit-Wasp using PrivateKeyFactory::fromWif PHP produce Deprecated ERROR

Tags: php

In my script this line of code using Bit-Wasp library for PHP gives me the following ERROR:

> Deprecated: Non-static method
>  BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\Factory\PrivateKeyFactory::fromWif() should not be called statically

What can be the problem? Searched Examples from the Lib and many other examples with Bit-Wasp none of it worked. ((

```
        use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
        .......

        $addrCreator = new AddressCreator();
        $transaction = TransactionFactory::build()
           ->input('some UTXO', 0)
           ->payToAddress(1000, $addrCreator->fromString('some addres'))
           ->payToAddress(1000, $addrCreator->fromString('some addres'))
           ->get();
        $hex = $transaction->getHex();
        $privateKey = 'WIF PRiVATE KEY';

        $tx = TransactionFactory::fromHex($hex);

         $utxos = [];
        foreach ($tx->getInputs() as $idx => $input) {
        $txid = $input->getOutPoint()->getTxId()->getHex();
        $vout = $input->getOutPoint()->getVout();
        $scriptPubKey = $input->getScript()->getBuffer()->getHex();

        $utxo = new Utxo(new OutPoint(Buffer::hex($txid, 32), $vout), new TransactionOutput(0, ScriptFactory::fromHex($scriptPubKey)));
        array_push($utxos, $utxo);
        }

        $priv = $factory->fromWif($privateKey);
        $priv = PrivateKeyFactory::fromWif($privateKey);
        $signer = new Signer($tx, Bitcoin::getEcAdapter());

        foreach ($utxos as $i => $utxo) {
           $signer->sign($i, $priv, $utxo->getOutput());
        }
        $signed = $signer->get();
        echo $signed->getHex() . PHP_EOL;
```

PS all other functions from the Lib work fine..  just cannot figure out how sign raw tx using WIF private key ((
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is no tested code, just an explanation.

A static method is called on a class directly and not on an instance.

It looks like the library changed. So create an instance and call the method on it like:

```
$factory = new PrivateKeyFactory();
$key = $factory->fromWif($privateKey);
```

Comment: Many thanks Markus. Tried it out - and looks like it worked.